# Superset with Athena: set workgroup based on user role

Tags: apache-superset, audit-trail, amazon-athena, pyathena

I'm working at a company that used to use AWS Athena and Quicksight to run sql queries and create dashboards, but now we have to use Apache Superset to do this.

While all users was using aws console, I could get Cloud Trail logs to send to the managers some reports of data consumption based on Athena workgroups or even idetify users that ran heavy queries, but since we migrate to Superset I lost the trace of user and workgroup because all queries are run using the same Athena connection...

Is this possible to pass the Athena workgroup based on user role (and maybe the username too) throught the conector?

I tried to find something on superset docs, but didn't find anything :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should be able to accomplish this by using Superset's [DB_DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset/config.py#L1166) to alter the connection string and set the workgroup, e.g., based on a Superset role.